# PostgreSQL12.4 install on CentOS8 Warning: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, centos8

I am installing PostgreSQL12.4 on a CentOS8 system by using the libs, PGDG, server and devel rpm's and getting the following warning:

**ldconfig: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf: No such file or directory**

The DB gets installed and I am able to do initdb successfully.

Can someone please tell me how to get rid of this warning? Also want to know if this warning will create any issues to the DB going forward?

Updating my post.. Adding the install commands:

```
rpm -Uvh --force --nodeps --badreloc --relocate /usr/pgsql-12=/opt/postgresql postgresql12-libs-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --force --nodeps --badreloc --relocate /usr/pgsql-12=/opt/postgresql postgresql12-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --force --nodeps --badreloc --relocate /usr/pgsql-12=/opt/postgresql postgresql12-server-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --force --nodeps --badreloc --relocate /usr/pgsql-12=/opt/postgresql postgresql12-devel-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm
```

FYI.. If I do not add `--relocate /usr/pgsql-12=/opt/postgresql` I do not see the warning.

Same installs on CentOS7 systems work with no warning..

Thanks

Comment: Probably no big problem, but what is at `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf`?

Comment: What where your exact install commands?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver -- Question updated with install commands

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -- `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf` has a soft link to `/etc/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf` which has a soft link to `/usr/pgsql-12/share/postgresql-12-libs.conf`... Since, I am doing `--relocate /usr/pgsql-12=/opt/postgresql`, the `postgresql-12-libs.conf` is now under `/opt/postgresql/share` .. I think thats what the problem is **but it works fine on CentOS7 system**

Comment: I updated the symbolic link `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf` to point to `/opt/postgresql/share/postgresql-12-libs.conf` but still the same error

Comment: Don't relocate the RPM then, or point the symbolic link to the correct location.